# OnTouch: при движении срабатывает ACTION_CANCEL

Tags: java, android, drag-n-drop, ontouchlistener

В приложении реализован DRAG&DROP.

Долгое нажатие вызывает перемещение элемента.Элементы представляют собой картинки в сетке `GridView` .В `OnTouch` необходимо обрабатывать действия при перемещении и отпускании элемента. Но в логах при касании вижу `ACTION_DOWN`, при опускании `ACTION_UP`, но при перемещении срабатывает `ACTION_CANCEL`.

Как я понимаю это происходит когда касание выходит за пределы слушателя.

Подскажите новичку, как решить проблему? Или скажем по другому - как отследить когда обьект перемещается и когда мы его отпускаем?

```
holder.handleView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "setOnTouchListener ");

            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG,"ACTION_DOWN");
                    return true;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG,"ACTION_UP");
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG,"ACTION_MOVE");
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG,"ACTION_CANCEL");
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: А почему вы реализуете drag&drop с помощью  View.OnTouchListener? Для этого предусмотрен специальный View.OnDragListener с подходящими событиями. Регистрируется соответственно с помощью setOnDragListener().

Answer (score 1):

воспользуйтесь RecyclerView у него есть целый класс для Drag&Drop и Swipe, ItemTouchHelper.

```
ItemTouchHelper th=new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.Callback(){
public int getMovementFlags(...){
return makeMovementFlags(ItemTouchHelper.UP|DOWN|LEFT|RIGHT,0);
}
public boolean isLongPressDragEnabled(){return true;}//разрешает Drag
//а метод onDrag в onMove(true -можно будет таскать,false-этот холдер нельзя таскать
public boolean onMove(RecyclerView rv,ViewHolder from,ViewHolder to){
return true;//from-холдер откуда начался Drag,to-куда переместили
}
});
th.attachToRecyclerView(RecyclerView);
//настройте RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(GridLayoutManager);
```